# How and where to add the amenity values in this json response

Tags: php, json, php-7

Here I have two tables (`rent_property`, `rent_amenity`). And I am using join query, where `rent_property.id`. I am using foreign key of `rent_amenity` `rentPropertyId`. Here I am real estate project, one project having multiple amenities so I am using two tables.

`rent_property`:

```
id     fullName    propertyName
-------------------------------
1       A          House Name1
2       B          House Name2
3       C          House Name3
4       D          House Name4
```

`rent_amenity`:

```
rentamenityId         rentPropertyId       amenityName
-------------------------------------------------------    
1                         1                 Lift
2                         1                 Gym
3                         2                 Power backup
4                         4                 Gym
```

My SQL query

```
$sql = "SELECT a.id,a.fullName,a.propertyName FROM rent_property a LEFT JOIN rent_amenity b ON  a.id = b.rentPropertyId WHERE a.city='1' AND a.propertyType IN ( '1','2' ) AND b.amenityName IN ( 'Gym' )  AND a.approveStatus!='Inactive' GROUP BY a.id order by a.id desc";

$result = $this->GetJoinRecord($sql);
```

My dynamic function

```
public function GetJoinRecord($query_string) {
        $con = $this->DBConnection();
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $query_string);

        if(@mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
                while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                    $record[] = $data;
                }

                mysqli_free_result($query);
        }

        mysqli_close($con); 
        return $record;
}
```

Based on my SQL query, I should get two records, and also I am getting correctly but I am not able to make my expected results, please see below I will post what I am currently getting as results:

```
{
"status": "success",
"message": "Data Found.",
"data": {
    "rent_id": [
        {
            "id": "4",
            "fullName": "D",
            "propertyName": "House Name4"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "fullName": "A",
            "propertyName": "House Name1"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

My main problem is I want to give response amenity also, I don't know where I have to add the amenity in this array. id 1 having two amenity and id 2 having one amenity

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pivot table to associate propertyId with amenityId and build a join query to fetch amentites related to a specific property.

Comment: Can you please update your answer , seriously i am not able to do